# Two normal subgroups with trivial intersection, one is characteristic, what about the other?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, $N, M$ normal subgroups with $N \cap M = {1}$ and $G = NM$.
I know $N$ is a characteristic subgroup of $G$. How could I show that $M$ is
characteristic as well?
 
Thank you.
P.S.: I also know that G is Abelian, but perhaps this fact isn't needed!?

Comment: Well, if $\,G\,$ is abelian then any subgroup is normal, so why is that even mentioned?

Comment: Because the statement would be a lot stronger if that wasn't needed.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't true. For example, consider $G=\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z_2}$. $0_{\mathbb{Z}}\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ is a characteristic subgroup of $G$, but $\mathbb{Z} \times 0_{\mathbb{Z}_2}$ is not.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see why $\mathbb{Z} \times 0_{\mathbb{Z}_2}$ is not characteristic. Could you help me?

Comment: @Boris There is an automorphism of $G$ that doesn't preserve $\mathbb{Z}\times 0_{\mathbb{Z}_2}$. This automorphism sends $(a, b)$ to $(a, b + [a])$ for every $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ and every $b \in \mathbb{Z}_2$. Here $[a]$ denotes the class of number $a$ modulo $2$.

Comment: Thank you Dan. I understand it now.